# get 400 error when trying to add a comma separated string to end of API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This API call takes a comma-separated list at the end of the URL.

If I put the data in like this at the end of the URL:

```
const matchDetails = await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature("getmatchdetailsbatch")}/${session}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${small[0]},${small[1]}`)
```

It works, and I get back what is expected.

However, the variable "small" contains about 700 id's. It wouldn't make sense to type this in 700 times. So I tried to do this:

```
const matchDetails = await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature("getmatchdetailsbatch")}/${session}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${small.join(",")}`)
```

And this gives me the 400 bad request error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:17)
at settle (settle.js:19)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I go about this?

Comment: What's the value of `small` when you get the 400 error

Comment: small is an array of id numbers

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of it when the AJAX call fails, could you put it in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or something?

Comment: Why not encode the commas using `encodeURI(YOUR_URL_HERE)`?

Comment: Here is the pastebin of the fail: https://pastebin.com/jktfQxdP

Comment: When I use that encodeURI() I still get the 400 error

Comment: Are you sure the API can take this many ids at one time? Many APIs will throttle the number of requests/responses. (I.e. It's unclear from the description, but the error may have nothing to do with your code and just be from too much data...)

Comment: I reduced the amount of data that is sent from 3k+ to 700. I no longer got the URI too long error after that

Comment: It looks like if I go above 25 id's at a time it gives me the 400 error. But less and it works. How would I go about getting the largest amount of data possible without to many api calls?

Comment: @CodyLee That makes sense! Then it sounds like this endpoint is not designed to take this many requests? I'm wondering if there is another endpoint in the API that would be better suited for your needs or if it would be helpful to rethink your architecture plan?

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get data for multiple matches at 1 time unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's pretty likely your GET request is too long. You should be passing these in the body of a POST request instead. If this isn't your API, and you cannot do that, you'll want to break it up into chunks. Request like 20 IDs at a time or something.

Comment: The problem is, I need as much data as possible to get accurate statistics. With their being 3k+ id's, I would probably cap before even finishing them right?

Comment: You can't POST the IDs?

Comment: It's not my API

Comment: Yeah it's possible you would hit an API Limit by splitting it into multiple requests. At that point the strategy would be to use a queueing system that would fire the requests on a schedule so you keep within their API lmits.